Header based authentication for the web app with ADFS as IDP
I am working on one use case where wish to authenticate my .net based web app (deployed on IIS server) with header based authentication flow. My web app currently uses username/password based login flow and I don't want to change it (Hence making the app SAML/OIDC compliant use case is eliminated).
Now, I want something like -

I will visit my web app and enter user credentials.
The IIS server acting as SP will redirect my request to ADFS IDP for authentication.
Once user authenticated successfully against the ADFS IDP, the username will be passed as header param to IIS server deployed web app.
User will be logged in successfully with SAML SSO flow but without enabling the app for SAML.

Am I thinking it correct way? Is this can be achieved in IIS server itself somehow?
To try the flow, I am successfully done with below -

Configured IIS sever for Shibboleth as SP service with enabling ISAPI filter option to protect web site URL
When I try to access the default IIS web server web site context, I am able to redirect to ADFS IDP for login, and after the successful authentication able to return to IIS server landing page.

But this is not my expectation. I want to use header based auth where my web app when accessed will be redirected to ADFS IDP (via IIS server acting as SAML SP) and once the auth is done successfully will be redirected to my web app with successful user authentication (instead of username/password based auth).
Please advice!!
